# If $A^5 = 0$, find the value of $(I-A)^{-1}$

Tags: matrices

If $A$ is a square matrix such that $A^5 = 0$, and $A_n \neq I$ for $1\leq n \leq4$, where $I$ is identity matrix, then $(I-A)^{-1}$ equals?

$(1)$ $A^4$

$(2)$ $A^3$

$(3)$ $I+A$

$(4)$ Not of these

Could someone help me with this question. I don't understand how to initiate.

Comment: Hint: Does$ \frac{1}{1-A}$ look like a familiar formula that you may know a series expansion for that could give you a nice clue into the formula of the inverse? Alternative hint: What happens if you multiply a matrix by its inverse? You only have 3 options to try, so trial and error could work well here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $(I-A)(I+A+A^2+A^3+A^4)=I-A^5=I$.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Is a counterexample for all of them.

Notice $(I-A)(A^4)=A^4-A^5=A^4-0=A^4$, which is not $I$.

Notice $(I-A)(a^3)=A^3-A^4\neq I$

Notice $(I-A)(I+A)=I-A^2\neq I$ as $A^2\neq 0$

Answer (score 0):

If $A^5=0$, then

$I^5-A^5=I-A^5=I$.

Recall the factorization

$x^5-y^5=(x-y)(x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4)$

which carries over to matrices if multiplication commutes, and matrix multiplication always commutes when one of the matrices is $I$.  So now you can identify $(I-A)^{-1}$ from the factorization and check the given choices against it.